# Modify default queryset in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, metaprogramming

I have added a 'cancelled' field to my model, is there a way to modify the model default query to something like cancelled=False ? without having to modify all my filter/exclude queries ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do this with a custom model manager and override the `get_queryset` function to always filter canceled=False.

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(canceled=False)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Blah blah
    objects = CustomManager()
```

Then when calling `MyModel.objects.all()` it will always exclude canceled objects. Here is a blog post I found helpful on the subject. http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/18/django-tips-using-properties-models-and-managers/

EDIT:
Perhaps a better approach with a custom manager would be to attach it to another property, other than objects, such as:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # Blah blah
    active = CustomManager()
```

And in your views your queries would look like `MyModel.active.all()`.

EDIT2:
Updated method spelling from `get_query_set` to `get_queryset` for modern versions of django.

Comment: you have to be VERY VERY careful with overriding default manager just like that. In this particular case, once item is cancelled, you won't ever find it with filter()/get().

Comment: Agreed. Would I typically supplement this approach with overriding get() to not use this filter if the pk is given. You probably would also want to change the admin queryset to return all including canceled. But if you rarely want canceled items in your queries this can be a reasonable approach.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to modify the behaviour of get_query_set to use additional parameters i.e. passed from somewhere, or use global variables like current login user info? thanks!

Comment: Depending on when you knew the parameters then you could pass them in the `CustomManager.__init__`. However the currently logged in user is is most certainly not available globally in a Django project.

Comment: Wonder where the `get_query_set` spelling comes from. I believe the correct method name is [get_queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset).

Comment: Yes the old name `get_query_set` was deprecated in 1.6 and removed in 1.8: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-1-8

Comment: This answer helped me fix a similar issue with Wagtail because you can't use `ordering = ('<field_name>', )` in a Wagtail model that inherits from `Page`.

Comment: If I were truly overriding the "default" so that I didn't have to refactor 90% of my views with the same filter, I'd perhaps make `objects = CustomManager()`, and have something like `objects_including_canceled = models.Manager()`. This is what I would try if I had a model with records that shouldn't quite be deleted, but aren't relevant to regular use. Depends on the data, though.

Answer (score 3):

You could write custom [query manager](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/custom_managers/), but I don't believe this is the right way to go. This would make an implicit, hidden condition for a filter, which would make code unreadable. Remember Zen of Python: `Explicit is better than implicit`. Detect places, where you need to add cancelled=False and just add this, that's the way you should do this.

Comment: I strongly disagree. What, then, would be the point of having custom managers? What is so implicit about `not_cancelled = CustomManager()` and then using MyModel.not_cancelled.all()?